# python raspberrypi gpio clock data read

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, clock, gpio

```
import pigpio
import time

start=time.time()

#setting up the IO
pi=pigpio.pi()
pi.hardware_clock(4,6400) #Setting GPIO4 as 6.4kHz clock

pi.set_mode(17,pigpio.INPUT)#GPIO17 as input
pi.set_mode(27,pigpio.INPUT)#GPIO27 as input
pi.set_mode(22,pigpio.INPUT)#GPIO22 as input
pi.set_mode(10,pigpio.INPUT)#GPIO10 as input
pi.set_mode(9,pigpio.INPUT)#GPIO9 as input
pi.set_mode(11,pigpio.INPUT)#GPIO11 as input
pi.set_mode(5,pigpio.INPUT)#GPIO5 as input
pi.set_mode(6,pigpio.INPUT)#GPIO6 as input


count=0

def readUnoOutput(gpio, level, tick):
    global count
    global start

    if count==0:
        start=time.time()

    count=count+1

    if count==128:
        end=time.time()

        timepersample= (end-start)/128
        samplerate= 1/timepersample

        print (end-start)
        print samplerate

#Set up GPIO callback
cb1=pi.callback(4, pigpio.RISING_EDGE, readUnoOutput)
```

Hi everyone,

Im using pigpio library to produce a clock signal on GPIO 4 of 6.4kHz then use this clock pulse in a callback function which should call this counter on each rising edge which we are calling a sample. So by my calculations 6400/128=50 and the samplerate should be 6400. I'm getting 28058. Seems simple cant figure it out.

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to use pin 4 as *both* an output (generating a clock pulse) and an input (reading that clock pulse)? I'm not sure I would expect that to work.

Comment: Hi larsks, thanks for your reply. I tried inputting the clock on pin 4 to another GPIO used as an input and using that as a trigger. Didn't make any difference.